# Does the AWS App Load-Balancer's Listener address a Target or a Target Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

In Amazon's description of its [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html), they include the following diagram (which I have seen replicated in other materials on the topic):

[image]

But they describe that Listener is configured to communicate with Target Groups, not the Targets, directly. If that is the case shouldn't there be only one arrow from the Listener to each Target Group that it targets?

Answer (score 0):

A Target Group is really just a logical construct to tell the load balancer what its targets are. The load balancer still does the work of "balancing the load" between the targets, thus it is aware of each available target and sends requests directly to them.

Comment: That makes sense, but I think this diagram is showing the relationship between Listeners and Targets and/or Target Groups... but my understanding is that Listeners do not configure relationships with Targets, but rather the Target Groups (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#forward-actions)

Comment: My understanding, from the paragraph above the diagram on the AWS site you linked, is that it illustrates request routing, in which case I would say it is accurate.

Comment: Heh, I was going to argue with you until I realized that I'd misinterpreted the Listener _components_ (as stated in the description) which are, in fact, the Listener _rules_ which influence the routing of the connections.